# Loop in dynamic context dataset and objects and properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, reflection, objectcontext

I have a context that I want to save all the data in each of the dataset in the context, and I don't want to write code based on each class type.  So I want to have list of type that I want to save them and I want to use loop in context.dataset and then loop on the properties.

Could you please help me :

```
     public static void saveAllFiles(Context context)
      {
            var objectTypes = new List<Type>();
        objectTypes.Add(typeof(Language));
        objectTypes.Add(typeof(Employee));

    foreach(Type objectType in objectTypes)
        {
            //var properties = objectType.GetProperties();
            var properties = objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var dataSetObjects = context.Set<objectType>().ToList();

            foreach(var dataSetObject in dataSetObjects)
            {

                 foreach( var  property in properties)
                 {
                     var value = property.GetValue(dataSetObject);
                     var name= property.Name;
                 }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what class your `Context` is referring to, but here's some code to give you the idea of how to get the property name and values:

```
public static void saveAllFiles(Context context)
{
    var objectTypes = new List<Type> {typeof (int), typeof (string)}; 

    foreach(Type objectType in objectTypes)
    {
        var properties = objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var dataSetObjects = context.Set(objectType);

        foreach(var dataSetObject in dataSetObjects)
        {
            foreach( var property in properties )
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(dataSetObject);
                var name = property.Name;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant use this line now :   context.Where(x => x.GetType() == objectType); mycontext has context.employees and context.languages , forexample , and I want to have a list of objects types to loop in that list

Comment: var objectTypes = new List<Type>();
            objectTypes.Add(typeof(Language));
            objectTypes.Add(typeof(Employee));

Comment: I have problem now on :  context.Set<objectType>().ToList()   and -> property.GetValue(dataSetObject)

Comment: What type is `context`?  It's hard for me to help since I don't know the type.  What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: the context is defined by myself inheriting :public class Context : DbContext, IContext

Comment: and it has :public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }

Comment: and   public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

Comment: What errors are you getting?  I just updated my sample to call `Set(objectType)`, but I don't have a DB to test against.  From what I can tell, this should be working. Can you debug this and provide a bit more info, such as what problems you're having and so on?  What you maybe need to do is create a helper method and look through `context.Languages` and `context.Employees`, but without more concrete details it will be hard for us to help.

Comment: I get this error :Error 2 The type or namespace name 'objectType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ....DataSeeder\SaveFiles.cs DataSeeder (DataSeeder\DataSeeder) 26 50
I cant use helper method as I have lots of dataset objects each diffferent class , and I dont want to write code for each of them , i want to loop somehow on all the dataset in context from type of my classes that I try to add their type to the list , and loop in them , you can see my edited code that I changed , I have the types in the list .

Comment: Oh, you can't call a generic method with a variable.  Look at my example, you have to pass in the type `context.Set(objectType)`